# How to read in a line in a bash script using IFS and while the line is being read create a new line between a specified charater

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a bash script that will read in a file that has one line and as it is reading the line and encounters whitespace create a new line then continue reading the line

**File trying to read**

```
david:69 jim:98 peter:21 sam:56 april:32
```

**This is my current bash script**

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName=$1 # storing the file
numberSpaces=$2 # will be used later to specify the number of spaces inbetween name:score

# Checking if no file was specified on the command line
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "No file specified"; exit 1;}

# Checking if the file entered on the command line exists
[ ! -f $fileName ] && { echo "File $fileName not found."; exit 2;}

# Internal Field Seperator(IFS) will read what is on the left and right of a specified char
while IFS='  ' read -r name;
do
  echo "$name"
  echo -e "\n"
done < $fileName

#while read -r line
#do
#   name="$line"
#   echo "Content of file - $name"
#done < "$fileName"
```

I am trying to get it to print to the screen

```
$ spacing.sh file.txt
$ david:69
$ jim:98
$ peter:21
$ sam:56
$ april:32
```

It is currently just printing the file contents on one line.
Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: As an aside, `echo -e` is bad form -- while bash supports it out-of-the-box (unless both `posix` and `xpg_echo` options are enabled), [the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html) makes its implementation doing anything put printing `-e` on output illegal (not just an unspecified extension, but actively a violation). Use `printf` instead -- either `printf '\n'` for constant strings, or `printf '%b' "$string_with_escape_sequences"` for dynamic ones.

Comment: Thank you @Charles Duffy for pointing out my bad form. I will make sure not to do that again in the future. Live and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one line:

```
tr -s " " "\n" < file.txt
```

Comment: Using IFS to match tabs, spaces and newlines: `tr -s "$IFS" "\n" < file.txt`

Comment: `tr` only works with single characters. for multiple chars use sed: `sed 's/ /\n\n/g' < file.txt`

Comment: Thank you @Ipor Sircer for your response work great and makes it easy to understand in one line of code. How would I use your method to create and double new line?

Comment: Thank you @Ipor Sircer you have been a big help. I will review the man page on sed.

Comment: sed is -almost- a programming language. Here is the basics: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `-d` option in `read` to make it read till the given delimiter:

```
while IFS= read -r -d ' ' name;
do
  echo "$name"
done < <(sed 's/$/ /' file.txt)
```

As per `help read`:

```
-d delim: continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather than newline
```

`sed` is used to inseart a space at end of line so that `-d` can work with space as delimiter,

Comment: Thank you @anubhava for your response but it seems that what you have posted does not print the last person and their score.

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the line into an array, then iterate over that array.

```
read -r -a fields < "$fileName"
for field in "${fields[@]}"; do
  echo "$field"
done
```

There's no need to set the value of `IFS` here, because the default (space, tab, newline) is sufficient to split a line delimited by arbitrary whitespace. One example of using `IFS` would be to subsequently split the colon-delimited parts of each field into *two* separate variables:

```
IFS=: read -r name count <<< "$field"   # field=david:69
# name=david
# count=69
```

Comment: I'd consider using `printf '%s\n' "$field"` -- if we're going word-by-word, there might be `-n` as a word.

Comment: Thank you @chepner for your response what you have suggested by taking the input and putting it into an array works great and is easy to modify for a custom output to the screen.